# Create a New Database with Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a way to create a new database in an ROR app automatically.

What I'm trying to do is create a new database for each new user that signs up for my site. so if the new user sign-up is successful a new database with some empty tables will be created.

Ever new user will get a new database and ever new database will be the same tables inside of it, but the information that each user will store will be different.

the reason I believe I need this due to if the user no longer want to use  my system I can provide them the information that they stored on my DB and then drop the DB and tables with great ease

what I'm looking for is something like the mysql_create_db() in php

Answer (score 0):

Dont you think that you are making a simple system complex? The way you are thinking is not scalable. For example, if you have thousands of user you have to create same amount of database tables!! Where most of the tables might be of no use. That is definitely ridiculous...

If you just want to achieve the followings

- Each user will have his own data.
- User may want to export data.
- If users close his account you will delete all his data

then you better think the whole as a single application with a single database. Design your database accordingly and better look for the best DRY practices of rails to implement that.

Comment: once i read the word "scalable" I did a huge face palm (i felt silly) it's just that my users would have users of their own to manage("sub-user"). my users would also have to manipulate data in tables related to their sub-users' table. I just thought this would be a easier solution for organization and report

Comment: You can share exactly what your application requires. We can provide a better single database suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good way to store users in a relational database, especially when using an application framework like ruby on rails which *depends* on your following convention over configuration.

Have one user Model and use the Devise and then Cancan gems to manage roles and permissions.  There's no need to reinvent the wheel here and that's just what this would be doing.

If there are other considerations such as size or performance, please spell them out in more detail.  The reasons you give (ease of management) would not be a good reason to go down that path.

It's an interesting idea and has uses in other areas, but really not so good for your standard user tables.

Comment: It’s more than a user table. The user table will be in my database but the users’ table  will be in there db, with all tables related to my users' main table. It’s just a concept I’m trying to figure out not a real app (well not yet). For example: if I got all auto parts dealers to store their inventory on my site i would like for them to have their own db because I didn’t want all my users’ data in one table! It just feels wrong and unsafe.